# Chartjs time in Xaxes

Tags: jquery, chart.js, axes

So i've been trying to generate time points in the Xaxes in my chart. I've found some examples, of different kinds but none of them have worked. The doc for *Chartjs* is a bit fuzzy for me. 
So how do i insert generated time in my xaxes?

```
 $j(function(){
new Chart(document.getElementById("Combo"),
    {"type":"bar",
    "data":{
    "labels":["08:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00"],
    "datasets":[{"label":"Bar Dataset",
    "data":[11,58,23,44,19,87,65,11,58,23,44,19,87,65],
    "borderColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)",
    "backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"},

    {"label":"Line Dataset",
    "data":[11,58,23,44,19,87,65,11,58,23,44,19,87,65
    ],
    "type":"line",
    "fill":false,
    "borderColor":"rgb(54, 162, 235)"}]},

    "options":{
    "scales":{
    "xAxes":[{
    time:{
    unit:"hour"}
    }],
    xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    format: "HH:mm",
    unit: 'hour',
    unitStepSize: 1,
    displayFormats: {
      'hour': 'HH', 

    },
}],
    "yAxes":[{
    "ticks":{"beginAtZero":true}
    }]
    }
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **`parser`** property instead of **`format`** *(deprecated)* to parse the date. Apart from that, you have few other syntax issues which need to be fixed.

Here is the revised version of your code :

```js
$(function() {
   new Chart(document.getElementById("Combo"), {
      "type": "bar",
      "data": {
         "labels": ["08:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00"],
         "datasets": [{
            "label": "Bar Dataset",
            "data": [11, 58, 23, 44, 19, 87, 65, 11, 58, 23, 44, 19, 87, 65],
            "borderColor": "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"
         }, {
            "label": "Line Dataset",
            "data": [11, 58, 23, 44, 19, 87, 65, 11, 58, 23, 44, 19, 87, 65],
            "type": "line",
            "fill": false,
            "borderColor": "rgb(54, 162, 235)"
         }]
      },
      "options": {
         "scales": {
            "xAxes": [{
               type: 'time',
               time: {
                  parser: "HH:mm", //<- use 'parser'
                  unit: 'hour',
                  unitStepSize: 1,
                  displayFormats: {
                     'hour': 'HH',
                  }
               }
            }],
            "yAxes": [{
               "ticks": {
                  "beginAtZero": true
               }
            }]
         }
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="Combo"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer - got of work early, thanks for the quick answer though!
It did not seem to solve my problem. Console on says unexpected }, so that not much to go on.

The syntax problem you were talking about is the $j thing im guessing. $ is our custom jquery-denominator.

so tldr; No still dont get it to work. Havent worked on it since i tried your code.

Comment: Besides the `$j` *(not so important)*, you also have other syntax issues, which is the main reason of your code not working. Please check your code thoroughly and make sure you haven't missed any brackets or commas